# getting JSON of uploaded pdf file in Django

Tags: python, django, api, server, django-views

I have uploaded a pdf file in django server from html page, now I want to show the JSON of same file on HTML page in response.

Someone please help me in this.

Comment: What JSON? Does the pdf contain JSON? Or do you want to return the title and location as JSON?

Comment: I want to return the data of file in JSON. Actually I have to do analysis on files by using ML engine and wants to show the data in JSON from server.